# Ordenar por un valor específico en Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Explico lo que tengo y lo que pretendo hacer, esta es la consulta en msyql.

```
select governor_candidate from governor order by id=3 desc;
```

Esta consulta me devuelve un listado de 5 registros, cuando yo cambio el numero en el campo id, este me muestra los registros, pero el primero de ellos es el id que digite, en este caso 3.

```
id  candidato

3   gober3

1   gober1

2   gober2
```

Para que esto?, es por que tengo un formulario para editar registros, y tengo un campo select que me consulta estos registros, entonces lo que yo quiero es que cuando retorne el formulario ya aparezca el usuario que anteriormente elegio como primera opcion, y de resto aparezcan los otros usuarios en el select si lo deseo cambiar. si hago esto en sql es perfecto, el problema es cuando paso esto a eloquen.

```
$somevar =governor::orderByDesc('id')->get();
```

Necesito buscar la manera de poderle pasar a 'id' un valor, pero no se como, alguien sabe si esto se puede?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los métodos orderBy y orderByDesc no pueden recibir valores específicos en Laravel, en ese caso la única opción que tienes es `orderByRaw`:

```
$somevar = governor::select('governor_candidate')
               ->orderByRaw("FIELD(id, 3) DESC")
               ->get();
```

Comment: Hermano me salvo la vida, nadie le había atinado, muchas gracias.

Comment: te doy un +1 por que cuando respondí no presté atención al hecho del valor específico del id para ordenar

Answer (score 1):

Con el método `orderByRaw()` ayúdate

Entonces debería verse así

```
$id = 3;
$somevar =governor::orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, ".$id." ) DESC"))->get();
```

Ahora si deseas obtener el valor de la columna `governor_candidate` entonces también deberás usar el método `select` así

```
$id = 3;
$somevar =governor::select('governor_candidate')
                  ->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, ".$id." ) DESC"))
                  ->get();
```

**aclaración no presté atención al valor específico del id y por eso edité mi respuesta**

Comment: Es innecesario y redundante utilizar `DB::raw()` dentro de `orderByRaw()`.

Comment: buen punto gracias por la observación, no tuve reparo en ese detalle y así lo venía usando, gracias @Shaz

Answer (score 0):

puedes ordenarlo de esta manera

```
$somevar =governor::select('governor_candidate')
                  ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                  ->get();
```

o de forma ascendente

```
$somevar =governor::select('governor_candidate')
                  ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
                  ->get();
```

y no te complicas demasiado y es mas facil si lo que quieres es solo ordenar

Comment: Es inncesario declarar un ordenamiento `asc` ya que ese es el valor que tiene inicialmente el método `orderBy` para trabajar